# Only first of two chained ranges executing

Tags: python

Consider the following simple loop which is producing the output that I desire:

```
import itertools as it
for e in range (0, 16):
    for i in it.chain(range(30, 53), range(1, 19)):
        print(e, i)
```

The scaled up version of this code I have built is not producing the desired outcome:

```
import json
import requests
import time
import datetime
import dateutil
import traceback
import os.path
import itertools as it

year_map = [2,89,213,359,542,803,1208,937,2025,2539,3115,4345,5476,6531,7794,9155,5826]
tournament_map = [26,114,243,421,579,903,1291,1645,2175,2689,3419,4940,5861,6978,8273]
years = [1999,2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015]

for i in range (0, 16):

    try:

        url = ('http://www.whoscored.com/tournamentsfeed/',str(year_map[i]),'/Fixtures/')
        url = ''.join(url)
        headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36',
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
        'Host': 'www.whoscored.com',
        'Referer': 'http://www.whoscored.com/'}

        for f in it.chain(range(30, 53), range(1, 19)):

            game_week = (str(years[i]), 'W', str(f))
            game_week = ''.join(game_week)

            params = {'d': game_week,
            'isAggregate': 'false'}

            response = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers)
            response2 = (url, str(params))
            response2 = ','.join(response2)

            json_data = response.content.replace("'", '"').replace(',,', ',null,')
            fixtures = json.loads(json_data)

            if len(fixtures) > 1:

                myfile = ",\n".join([", ".join(str(x) for x in fixture) for fixture in fixtures])  # `fixtures` is a nested list
                print myfile
                myfile2 = myfile + '\n'
                time.sleep(20)

                #create text file here


    except Exception as exc:

        print response2
        print exc
        print response.status_code
        print response.text
        pass
        time.sleep(20)

print "-" *120
```

When I have run this version of the code however it only iterates through the first of the two chained ranges. In this context that produces data for the part of the football data being browsed between August and December of a season. The code then ceases execution without error.

Can anyone see anything within the code that is causing this to happen? I'm stumped.

Thanks

Comment: The loops work fine and values from both `range()` calls are included; are you certain you diagnosed the issues correctly? Also note that since Python 2 `range()` produces list objects, you may as well use `range(30, 53) + range(1, 19)` once, then iterate over the result. Or switch to using `xrange()` here.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why you place weeks 1 - 18 before weeks 30 - 52 for a given year though.

Comment: @MartijnPieters hi martijn. the way the data comes from the server is that weeks 30-52 and 1-18 of two different years are assigned the same year value as they are part of the same sporting season. the output i get printed to the log is only weeks 30-52 running then the code completing execution. the contents of the output text files also reflects this. i will have another look at the code and your suggestions around range syntax to use moving forward.

Comment: Most likely, it didn't enter the `if len(fixtures) > 1:` condition for some of the loop iterations, so nothing was printed. Put a `print` at the beginning of the loop to see if all loop iterations are performed.

Comment: I am executing code now without the if statement in question. will let you know the outcome.